# already four days now, still have not reslove this challenge

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, mount, livewires

What am i not doing right? i'm woking on a livewire project that needs to get the grade_id's to show in show-component.blade.php, from Modules table which is related to a Grades table. My challenge is that, it only show a particular id, like the one in the mount section, so if i change it to 2 it will only show id's that are 2's, though thats really what i wanted but i can be change it manually.

```
use App\Models\Grade;
use App\Models\Module;
use Livewire\Component;

class ShowComponent extends Component
{
    public $modules;
    public $grades;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->modules = Module::all()->where("grade_id", "1");

    }

    public function render()
    {
       return view('livewire.show-component');
    }
}
```

=========================================================================

show-component.blade.php

```
@foreach($modules as $module)
        <div class="flex flex-col grid-cols-12 md:grid text-gray-50">


                <div class="flex md:contents">
                    <div class="relative col-start-2 col-end-4 mr-10 md:mx-auto">
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-center w-6 h-full">
                        <div class="w-1 h-full bg-green-500 pointer-events-none"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="absolute w-6 h-6 -mt-3 text-center bg-green-500 rounded-full shadow top-1/2">
                        <i class="text-white fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-full col-start-4 col-end-12 p-4 my-4 mr-auto bg-green-500 shadow-md rounded-xl">
                        <h2 class="mb-1 text-lg font-semibold">
                            {{ $module->name }}
                        </h2>
                        <p class="w-full leading-tight text-justify">

                            <a href="{{ url('storage/videos'.$module->video) }}">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-5 h-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM9.555 7.168A1 1 0 008 8v4a1 1 0 001.555.832l3-2a1 1 0 000-1.664l-3-2z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                </svg>
                            </a>

                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    @endforeach
```

==================================================================

Module's Model

```
public function grade()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Grade::class, 'grade_id', 'id');

}
```

===============================================================

Grade's Model

```
public function curricula()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Curriculum::class, 'curricula_id', 'id');
}


public function module()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Module::class);
}
```

Comment: How do you want to change the `grade_id` ?

Comment: By the way.  This `$this->modules = Module::all()->where("grade_id", "1");` is NOT good practice since it fetches all modules into memory and then filters to the grade_id=1 as a secondary operation.  You should use `$this->modules = Module::where("grade_id", "1")->get();` to only load modules of grade 1

Comment: i want it to get related grade_id's in the modules table, becos currently it is not

Comment: thanks for you prompt reply, i try your solution but still giving the selected id which is 1, but if i change it to 2 manually it get id's that relate to 2 even if you click on grade 5 for example which suppose to give me id thar relates to grade 5 but instead it keep giving me id 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is ..

Add

```
public $grade_id;
```

Then in mount

```
$this->modules = Module::where("grade_id", $this->grade_id)->get();
```

When you load your component you can pass grade_id to it

Answer (score 1):

If you want all `Module` records stored in your database table, you want to remove the `where` condition which is limiting the return value.

```
$this->modules = Module::all();
```

If you want just the `grade_id`s from your `modules` table, use `pluck`:

```
$grade_ids = Module::pluck('grade_id');
```